# How to apply styles to specific element under parent only if it's the first element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

I need to apply styling to a `p` tag *only* if it's the first element under the parent. I've tried searching Google and Stack Overflow, but I may not be typing in the right searches to get what I need as I couldn't find an example of what I need to do.

What CSS could I use if I need to change the text to red in the code below?

```
<div class="main">
  <p>This will be red.</p>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `:first-child` selector will do this.

```css
.main p:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>This will be red.</p>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main">
  <p class = "first">This will be red.</p>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <p>This will not be red.</p>
</div>
```

Just add a simple class and then in your CSS have `.first {color: red; }` and for your other `p {color: blue; //or whatever colors}`

*It may seem tedious but it's really simple to just make classes or IDs and add them to your elements that you want to be more specifically styled.

OR just do what Coker suggested, that works too!

Answer (score 0):

All it takes is a few line of CSS to acomplish this.

```
.main  p:first-child {

  color: red;
}
```

Here is the code working with your HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/f8Ljkpt5/

Comment: OP's question is _"I need to apply styling to a p tag only if it's the first element under the parent."_ While your code works for their example, OP's not looking to to only apply to `.main:first-child` - just `.main p:first-child`