# I have two same cIass name and one style is possible to apply style for first div class?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I have Two div like :

```html
<div class="circle">
<div class="circle">
```

and I have a style:

```
.circle{
    width="100";
    height="200";
}
```

In this case I the css apply to first div only is this possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply styles to specific element under parent only if it's the first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902984/how-to-apply-styles-to-specific-element-under-parent-only-if-its-the-first-elem)

Answer (score 3):

use `.circle:first-child` and you solve you problem

```css
.circle:first-child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">First child</div>
<div class="circle">Second child</div>
```